# Dynamically deploying Jenkins slaves on google compute engine for github commits

Tags: github, jenkins, google-compute-engine

This is a question of integration:

I would like to run Jenkins on Google Compute Engine.  I can do this, but I will quickly break my budget if I leave an 8-core virtual machine running at all times.  As a solution, I think I can leave a micro instance with a low amount of memory powered on and acting as the jenkins master running at all times.  It seems that I should be able to configure github to startup a jenkins slave (with 8 cores) whenever a push is performed.  How do I connect github post-commit hooks to Google Compute Engine to achieve this?  A complete answer is probably asking too much, but even just pointers to the relevant documentation would be helpful.

Alternatively, how would you solve my problem?

Comment: I'm investigating GCE for our Jenkins instance because they do 10 minutes and then per-minute billing sort of like CloudBees but much cheaper and not like EC2 where it's hourly all the time. I don't have an answer but my cursory searches don't seem to bring up anything as well. I wonder if there's an equivalent of `fog` for Java though which someone could possibly produce a plugin for Jenkins with though.

Comment: Hey, I think I found something. There is something like `fog`! https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JClouds+Plugin http://jclouds.apache.org/reference/providers/#compute-apis . I've never tried this but maybe it's possible with this.

Comment: That looks promising -- please do report back if you give it a try

Comment: My organization is in the still kicking the tires stage on CI. We'll probably go with EC2 for now since it is well supported and optimize later to GCE. but yeah, sure, will most definitely report back if we do. Maybe you should post this question in some GCE forum since I'm sure that per-minute billing is something that Google would love to promote to CI users as an advantage over EC2 and friends.

Comment: Have this question been resolved yet? If yes, please let us know how you've decided to proceed. In case you haven't yet solved this, I added an answer below with a sketch of how you might make this work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mishabrukman , I haven't resolved it yet, and I'm re-analyzing the available options again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a preemptible instance that automatically gets restarted every few minutes.  I had to setup the instance manager to perform this restart, and I had to use the API, since this is a bit of an advanced and peculiar use of the features.

Answer (score 2):

You can run an AppEngine instance and use the URL it provides as the target of your GitHub on-commit web hook. This way, you won't be charged unless the instance is actually running, which may even be cheaper than running a micro instance 24x7 on Compute Engine.

You can then start/stop instances on Compute Engine or trigger actions on them from your code running on App Engine.

Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17393574/3618671) which has an answer for how to authenticate to Compute Engine from code running on AppEngine.