# Dynamically deploying Jenkins slaves on google compute engine using jclouds plugin

Tags: jenkins, google-compute-engine

How do I setup the Jenkins plugin named Jcloud to work with Google Compute Engine?  Some of the blanks seem to be centered around other cloud platforms, such as machine core count and memory.

Comment: Note that this is a more specific version of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223102/dynamically-deploying-jenkins-slaves-on-google-compute-engine-for-github-commits